# Editing text file when updating row

Tags: c#

I am able to read my text file however when I go and click my edit button it moves all the current rows in the text file to the top row and doesn't update anything. Also how would I go about adding a row to the text file without moving the rows?

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BugTrackers cs = Bugs[index];
  // DisplayBugs();
  // Update datafile
  UpdateBugsInfo();
}
private void UpdateBugsInfo()
{
  if (lstBugs.SelectedIndex > -1)
  {
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt", false);
    for (int i = 0; i <= Bugs.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsName);
      sw.Write(",");
      sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsDesc);
    }
    sw.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try explaining this again. Maybe say it out loud and listen to what you say? I can't quite figure out what you are asking. In particular, what kind of app this? If your question is about why all your text gets written to a single line, that's likely because you don't write a line separator between lines. What you are writing is `Nane1,Desc1Name2,Desc2Etc3,EtcDesc3`

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamWriter` object you are creating is having wrong parameter value for **append**. You need to set that as `true` OR just remove that parameter since it’s default value is `true`.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt", true);
```

OR

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt");
```

**Here is the link from Microsoft.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_

You are also not using the `using` statement, which ensures the `StreamWriter` object is removed from memory when no longer needed. Please go through this article to understand it better.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter

Hope this helps!

Comment: When the Edit Button is selected it doesn't update the text File.  Instead it moves all rows of entries into one single line.  Why is that?'code' UpdateBugsInfo()
        { if (lstBugs.SelectedIndex > -1)
            { System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt");

                for (int i = 0; i <= Bugs.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsName);
                    sw.Write(",");
                    sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsDesc);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: That’s because you are not adding line break in the for block.  You need to add "sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);" BELOW  "sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsDesc);" within the "for loop".

Comment: Still not working correctly. It saves the file but isn't updating the row

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. Plz provide sample of your input, expected output and output by code.

Comment: What it should do is update the entry in the file and save it.  So if I have a misspelled word or need to update the row it will with a button.'code'      private void UpdateBugsInfo()
        { if (lstBugs.SelectedIndex > -1) {System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt"); for (int i = 0; i <= Bugs.Count - 1; i++)
                { sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsName);
                    sw.Write(",");
                    sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsDesc);
                    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: What this should do is allow me to read a file that has data in it and edit the row if needed also add or remove lines of data.  I am using a lstbox to display the selected name and then text boxes to relist the name and description.  The two textboxes will allow me to edit add or delete the entry.

Comment: It would be faster if you can share your code and which I can check. Provide sample of expected output and current output along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace BugTracker
{
    struct BugTrackers
    {
        public string BugsName;
        public string BugsDesc;

    }

    public partial class YoungKidsBugTracker : Form
    {
        // Field to hold a list of BugTrackers objects
        private List<BugTrackers> Bugs = new List<BugTrackers>();
        private int index; // index fo selected bugs in combobox

        public YoungKidsBugTracker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                //Declare a varialble to hold Bugs Name
                StreamReader inputFile;   // To Read the file
                string line;              // To hold a line from the file

                // Create an instance of the Bug Accounts
                BugTrackers entry = new BugTrackers();

                // Create a delimeter array
                char[] delim = { ',' };

                // Open the file and get a StreamReader Object
                inputFile = File.OpenText("smBugs.txt");

                // Read the file's contents
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    // Read a line from the file
                    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    // Tokenize the line
                    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                    // Stores the tokens in the entry object
                    entry.BugsName = tokens[0];
                    entry.BugsDesc = tokens[1];

                    // Add the entry object to the combobox
                    Bugs.Add(entry);
                }
                // Close the File
                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display an error message
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void lstBugs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the index of the sselected item
            index = lstBugs.SelectedIndex;

            // Display Bug Information
            DisplayBugs();
        }

        private void DisplayBugs()
        {
            //Show Data
            txtBugsName.Text = Bugs[index].BugsName;
            rtxtBugDesc.Text = Bugs[index].BugsDesc.ToString();
        }

        private void YoungKidsBugTracker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Read the Bugs.txt file
            ReadFile();

            // Display Bug Information
            BugNameDisplay();
        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BugTrackers cs = Bugs[index];
           // DisplayBugs();
            // Update datafile
            UpdateBugsInfo();
        }
        private void UpdateBugsInfo()
        {
            if (lstBugs.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("smBugs.txt");

                for (int i = 0; i <= Bugs.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(Bugs[i].BugsName);
                    sw.Write(",");
                    sw.WriteLine(Bugs[i].BugsDesc);
                   // sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        private void BugNameDisplay()
        {
            // Display the list of Bug Names in the List Control
            foreach (BugTrackers entry in Bugs)
            {
                lstBugs.Items.Add(entry.BugsName );
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

This is the code in its entirety. I have a list box with 2 text boxes to hold the bug name and description. I have 3 buttons Add, Edit and Delete. If an item is selected from the listbox it will display the bugname and description. If the entry needs updated changes are made and will change the information needed. If a new bug is added you would use the add button same for the delete button.